# How to Zoom in on text in Mac Mail without changing the text size when composing a message

Tags: macos, email

I am relatively new to Mac Mail and often find I would like to zoom in on some text temporarily to read more thoroughly when composing a message.

The Command+ feature which works on email that I've received doesn't seem to work in Mac Mail.  The only solution I've found so far is changing the font size, but I would actually prefer to keep the font size the same for recipients; it would be cumbersome to flip back and forth.

I recently upgraded to the El Capitan 10.11.1 OS X.

Thanks!